# Common WHERE Clause Across Multiple Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I have a number of queries that all use the same `WHERE` clauses for example:

```
--Query1
CREATE PROC Query1
    @Param int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        field2,
        COUNT(field2)

    FROM
        some_table

    WHERE
        field1 = condition1
        AND field2 = @Param

    GROUP BY
        field1
END

--Query2
CREATE PROC Query2
    @Param int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        field2,
        COUNT(field2)

    FROM
        some_table

    WHERE
        field1 = condition1
        AND field2 = @Param

    GROUP BY
        field2
END
```

I'm wondering if I can create a function or some sort that I can use across the queries to prevent repeating the code and for better maintainability?

Comment: Those queries are identical, your question does not make sense

Comment: I have amended to make the queries different. The purpose behind the question though is about the common `WHERE` clauses being used across the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use an inline table valued function for this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.some_function 
(   
    @Param INT
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
      SELECT *
      FROM   some_table
      WHERE  field1 = condition1
             AND field2 = @Param
)
```

Then your procedures would use

```
SELECT field1,
       COUNT(field1)
FROM   dbo.some_function(@Param) 
GROUP  BY field1
```

or

```
SELECT field2,
       COUNT(field2)
FROM   dbo.some_function(@Param) 
GROUP  BY field2
```

If you do use `*` in the function definition you must remember to refresh it if the underlying table definition changes with [`sp_refreshsqlmodule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx) to avoid strange results so for that reason it is probably better to just list the columns explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Martin. From experience, how difficult do you find it to maintain the selected fields in the function in comparison to just selecting all the data and refreshing the table definition? If I was to take the approach of selecting all the data, how often does the table definition need to be refreshed?

Comment: @Gareth - You only need to refresh the function if you add or drop columns in the underlying table. If you do your development in SSDT the deployment scripts already take care of this. Otherwise I suggest listing the columns explicitly rather than `*` as it won't just end up doing the wrong thing silently if you forget.

Comment: Thanks again martin. Will give this a go when I get back.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a view to run the queries against, the  you have the same issue with refreshing.  If you create the view with `select *`, you make the view with the columns that match the `*` at the time you created the view.

```
CREATE_VIEW func_view AS 
SELECT *
      FROM   some_table
      WHERE  field1 = condition1
```

Then, run your selects like `select * from func_view group WHERE field2 = @Param`

Comment: Views have the same problem - hence existence of `sp_refreshview` - and can't be parameterised.

Comment: Right, I edited to show that I meant put the static part of the query in the view.  Also, I misunderstood you about the refresh stuff, when you create the view and the function using `select *` it creates it with whatever * means at the time you created it.